# yui zindex not getting set

Tags: html, yui, z-index

I have a YUI dialog with z-index set to 1000. Then there is a little ul/li based (not a select) dropdown on the parent page which has a z-index 100. This (always) works perfect on my dev box - the dropdown goes behind the dialog.

But on a staging site, I get a strange behavior where the dropdown peeps through the dialog. When I check the dialog z-index using firebug, it is set to 4! The dropdown z-index is still 100. This happens only for particular cases.

I was wondering what might be causing to change the z-index of the dialog to 4 when my code sets it to 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Since the problem is only happening for "particular cases," it sounds like a bug in your sw rather than in yui.

Some ideas:

- Carefully check your css in the "particular cases" to make sure that your css file is not over-riding the z-index value. (Your css should not set the zindex value if it is being set programmatically by YUI dialog.)
- Check your code where you create the dialog to ensure that your z-index setting has been set for each instantiation of the dialog. It could be that the z-index is being reset when the dialog is hidden.

Comment: I have checked these things and nothing seems wrong. When I say "particular cases" - we have different albums in our application where users can upload photos etc. This problem is appearing only for some of the albums.

Comment: Does it ever happen immediately after page load? Or is it only after the dialog has already been shown then hidden? Sorry that I don't have more specifics for you. Firebug has a break on dom changes feature that may help. You need to see if the z-index is being set, then reset to a bad value or if the initial set is not happening for some reason.

Comment: It happens immediately after the page load when the dialog is opened for the first time. As you said, the initial set is not happening for some reason because I set the zIndex in the constructor of Dialog which is bound to execute every time dialog opens for the first time.

Comment: When you initially create the dialog, be sure to give it some content. There is/was a bug that the dialog's dom structure doesn't get set up correctly unless it has content. Also, try setting the z-index explicitly on the returned dialog top el rather than depending on the constructor to set it.

Comment: I do give some content while creating the dialog and I have also tried setting the zIndex explicitly at a couple of places like before show(), on changeContentReady etc. but still no luck. I have observed that when I execute the same scenario on IE8, the mask behind the dialog turns complete black. I read on web that this is an issue with IE8 but then it happens only on those particular cases when other browsers give the behavior I originally talked about.